# 2 table views in one view ios

Tags: ios, swift3

I have 2 tables in my view [image]

How can I call both custom cells into `cellForRowAt...`

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "incomeCell", for: indexPath) as! ViewControllerTableViewCell

        return cell
    }
```

How can I add `expensesCell` in the same function so both my tables are populated with data?

Comment: You can use the tableview parameter to filter the tableview and then process the custom cell

Comment: You can differentiate two table by it;s name like if tabl1 {}elas {}

Comment: Why do you use 2 tableviews? You can use one tableview with multiple sections.

Comment: how about using __1__ table-view with __2__ sections?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use arrays for elements for different tableviews so you will have:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if tableView == incomeTable {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "incomeCell", for: indexPath) as! ViewControllerTableViewCell

        return cell
    } else {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "expenseCell", for: indexPath) as! ViewControllerTableViewCell

        return cell
    }
}
```

And remember about:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    if tableView == incomeTable {
        return incomeElements.count
    } else {
        return expensesElements.count
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect, that's exactly what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution is to add an outlet for one of the table views

```
@IBOutlet weak var incomeTableView : UITableView!

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if tableView == incomeTableView {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "incomeCell", for: indexPath) as! ViewControllerTableViewCell
        return cell
    } else {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "expensesCell", for: indexPath) as! ViewControllerTableViewCell
        return cell
    }
}
```

But you can achieve the same appearance with **one** table view using sections.

Comment: Thank you, I'm just learning ios development and I need to separate tables to have separate scrolls, am not sure how sections work but will definitely take a look into that.